# charts  in HTML5?

Tags: html

I am new to HTML5.I see lot of charts using sencha,fusion.Is it possible drawing charts without using any scripts in HTML5?Have they used scripts?If it is possible only through scripts,why should we use HTML5? is Normal HTML Enough?

Comment: You mean without using JavaScript?

Comment: YES...If we do through javascript, why do we need HTML5? Normal HTML is enough?

Comment: HTML5 was not created to solve *your* XML parsing problems in my humble opinion :) HTML is a mark up language. you need javascript to parse your xml for drawing charts and all.

Comment: You could transform XML to SVG using XSLT, but this would still be an programming type solution and isn't really HTML5 specific.  Charting in HTML5 is something you would probably do with the canvas element with scripting.  While some parts of HTML5 are designed to eliminate the need for scripting, others actually add more JavaScript APIs for consumption, the canvas interface is one of them.

Comment: canvas only is not enough for charts? Both canvas and scripts are needed.Am I right?

Comment: You can make perfectly fine bar charts without Javascript by using `<div>`s and coloring, sizing and positioning them using CSS on the server-side. It entirely depends on what your charts should be or do.

Comment: The canvas itself doesn't do anything.  It is just a blank element that you can draw on using a JavaScript API, similar to drawing you might do in Java or with WinForms.  To draw a chart on the canvas, you would first need to read the XML and then use your own drawing functions to draw the chart on the canvas.  There's nothing automatic about it and you would have to put quite a bit of logic into it.

Comment: What kind of chart are you trying to make?  If its a pie chart or something complex, you would definitely want to try using the canvas.  If its a bar chart, it may be the most painless to use <div> elements and CSS for positioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 has something called canvas that can show [beautiful charts like this](http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery/).

Now, do draw a chart, we need data primarily. That is xml, json or javascript array or something like that. HTML5 is just the latest version of HTML which makes it a Markup Language.

HTML just can render graphs into the screen once your script supply it all your data.

The point is, HTML5 cannot parse your custom data. And also to make it compatible to our good old IE, who apparently have not heard of canvas yet, , we need libraries like [explorercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/).

And to make this drawing simpler and cross browser friendly, we use libraries like

1. [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)
2. [RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/)

Comment: why should we use scencha or fusion charts for mobile devices? cant we make touch facility ourself through javascript for iPhone and iPad?

Comment: yes. the same reason why we use jquery. its a javascript library that makes the trivial tasks easy. also sencha has a flash player version which is irrelevant if you are using iphones as apple hates flash :)

Comment: You are wrong..scencha is not using flash..it is purely based on HTML5 and scripts.Fusion is only based on Flash..Plase check and give comment

Comment: oh yes. sorry. but the point is they are libraries that will save a lot of coding

Answer (score 0):

if you want performance and beauty you have this - http://www.highcharts.com

thanks